# Magento 1.9 Duplicated skin does not result insame design

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, skin

i have a multishop, fir one is leroidutshirt.frezalsublimation.fr and the second one is seizeart.frezalsublimation.fr
I copied the skin (RWD) of the first one and applied to the second one.
I copied the homepage layout in the CMS tab.
However, the second one does not show the image, and i noticed the layout is not what i thought
are there any other tweaking to do? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that CSS and JS is cached and stored on store level. When the CSS or JS is combined and minified, it generated a unique hashed key that is based on the store ID and timestamp (among other things). Make sure you copy the entire theme for the store (`app/design/frontend/` and `/skin/frontend`/) and make sure you flush the JS and CSS cache (System -> Cache Management) before trying again.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I had to also duplicate the layout files

Comment: Yes, the layout files are also in `app/design/frontend/`